# Shared Hystrix command pool by service deployed on 2 instances

Tags: hystrix

I want to create a Hystrix Command pool for 1 use case served by a service which is deployed in 2 containers.
Will Command pool be shared across both instances or each instance will have its own Command pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circuit breakers and thread pool created by Hystrix are NOT SHARED between instances. Each instance has its own metrics for Hystrix command and thread pool for each thread pool group.

Comment: Thanks a mill for reply. Do you know any other api I can use to limit the requests handled by my service which is deployed across multiple instances. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: If you are going to use Spring Cloud Gateway, you can limit the number of requests across instances using redis - ratelimit. But just with Hystrix, you can't do that.